# Change language based on user selection on expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, internationalization, expo

Just wondering if there's any way to change the language of an expo app with typescript based on user selection (so not device language).
I read through the docs on expo https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/localization/ but there doesn't seem to be anything on it.

Below is what I have currently, and it's only working for device set language.

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import I18n from 'i18n-js';

// import translations
import en from './en.json'
import zh from './zh.json'

// bind translations to i18n
I18n.translations = {
  en,
  zh
}

// set phones language
const getLanguage = async() => {
  try {
    const choice = Localization.locale
    I18n.locale = choice.substr(0, 2)
    I18n.initAsync()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

getLanguage()

// export function
export function t(name: string) {
  return I18n.t(name)
}
```

Only thing now is that I don't know how to pass a language based on user input.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

try using [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/). It has the [changeLanguage](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage) api available.

Answer (score -1):

You should use React.Context to share the locale in the different components.

See the example here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/localization/